# htaccess only match specific file types in root

Tags: .htaccess

I have a subdirectory called `/i/` where I have images and videos saved. Files like png, gif, and mp4.
I have some code in the .htaccess file to silently redirect from root to /i.

Example:
domain.com/awE1.png is silently redirected to domain.com/i/awE1.png

Code:

```php
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/i/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico|mp4)$ i%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

The problem is, if there is a file in the root folder, or another subdirectory such as /s and the file is an image, it will just result in a 404 error. Is there any way I can make .htaccess only look for the predefined file extenstions in the root folder?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not rewrite files existent under root or other directory, like this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/i/ [NC]
RewriteRule \.(?:jpe?g|gif|bmp|png|tiff|ico|mp4)$ i%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

With the first RewriteCond, it rewrites only nonexistent image file, any file that exists in other directory is not rewrited to /i/ folder.

Comment: This still (unnecessarily) checks requests that are outside the root folder. This could be optimized to check only root requests by modifying the regex... eg. `^[^/]+\.(?:jpe?g|gif`....

Comment: OK Mr White, very nice. I'm grocer in the day, at the evening, I could take my old job: programmer.